# TfidfVectorizer remove features with zero tf-idf score

Tags: python, tf-idf

I want to cluster documents using python. First I generate document x terms matrix with tf-idf score as below:

```
tfidf_vectorizer_desc = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=0.9,use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem)
%time tfidf_matrix_desc = tfidf_vectorizer_desc.fit_transform(descriptions) #fit the vectorizer to text
desc_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer_desc.get_feature_names()
```

The matrix shape is (1510, 6862)

The score of each terms of the first document:

```
dense = tfidf_matrix_desc.todense()
print(len(dense[0].tolist()[0]))
dataset0 = dense[0].tolist()[0] 
phrase_scores = [pair for pair in zip(range(0, len(dataset0)), dataset0) if pair[1] > 0]
print(len(phrase_scores))
```

Output :

- print(len(dense[0].tolist()[0])) -> 6862
- print(len(phrase_scores)) -> 48
  *The first document only has 48 terms that are more than 0.0.

Now I want to identify all features (terms) that have 0 tfidf score for a given dataset from the matrix. How can I achieve this?

```
for col in tfidf_matrix_desc.nonzero()[1]:
    print(feature_names[col], ' - ', tfidf_matrix[0, col])
```

Comment: How would a feature always equal zero if `min_df=0.1` and `max_df=0.9` and you don't pre-specify the vocabulary?

Comment: I have modified the question, and included an example where the tf-idf scores of the terms for the first dataset with zeros.

Comment: See the documentation for [`TfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names).

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone would need something similar, what I use is the following:

```
# Xtr is the output sparse matrix from TfidfVectorizer
# min_tfidf is a threshold for defining the "new" 0
def remove_zero_tf_idf(Xtr, min_tfidf=0.04):
    D = Xtr.toarray() # convert to dense if you want
    D[D < min_tfidf] = 0
    tfidf_means = np.mean(D, axis=0) # find features that are 0 in all documents
    D = np.delete(D, np.where(tfidf_means == 0)[0], axis=1) # delete them from the matrix
    return D
```